# MapStrateToProps doesn't connect to the local storage using redux and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have a web app that is suppose to show a list of notes made by the user on the dashboard if said list exist (that is if the user wrote any note at all). I wrote the reducer, the actions and I connected state and dispatch in order for it to work. But for some reason the notes created don't appear once in the dashboard when I write them, I already made sure that the ADD_NOTE action gets fired and that the reducer updates the data in redux, but in the dashboard component that data disappears.

This is my reducer.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_NOTE":
            return [
                ...state,
                action.note
            ];
        case "REMOVE_NOTE":
            return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id); 
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And those are my actions

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const addNote = ({ title = "", body = ""} = {}) => ({
    type: "ADD_NOTE",
        note : {
            title,
            body,
            id : uuidv4()
    }
}); 

export const removeNote = ({ id } = {}) => ({
    type: "REMOVE_NOTE",
    id
});
```

This is the component that holds the create note form.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CreateNote extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
      this.onBodyChange = this.onBodyChange.bind(this);
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

      this.state = {
         title: "",
         body: "",
         error: ""
      } 
   }

   onTitleChange(e){
      const title = e.target.value;
      this.setState({ title });
   }

   onBodyChange(e){
      const body = e.target.value;
      this.setState({ body });
   }

   onSubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      if(!this.state.title || !this.state.body){
         this.setState({ error : "Please fill in all gaps"});
      } else {
         this.setState({ error: ""});
         const data = { title: this.state.title, body: this.state.body}
         this.props.onChange(data);
      }
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
         {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
         <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
         <label>Put a title for your note</label>
         <input 
            placeholder="Title"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.title}
            autoFocus
            onChange = {this.onTitleChange}
         />
         <label>Write your note</label>
         <textarea 
            placeholder="Note"
            value={this.state.body}
            autoFocus
            onChange = {this.onBodyChange}
         />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </form>
         </div>
      );
   }
}


export default CreateNote;
```

And this is the component that fires the ADD_NOTE action

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CreateNote from "./actions/CreateNote";
import Header from "./Header";
import { addNote } from "../actions/noteActions"
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Create extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
   }
   eventHandler(data){
      this.props.addNote(data);
      this.props.history.push("/");
   }

   render(){
      return (
         <div>
            <Header />
            <CreateNote onChange = {this.eventHandler}/>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   addNote: (note) => dispatch(addNote(note))
 });

 
 export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Create);
```

And finally this is the dashboard component that renders the notes if they exist

```
import React from "react";
import ListItem from "./actions/ListItem";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ListGroup = (props) => (
    <div>
        {
            props.notes.length === 0 ?  <h1>Write a note!</h1> : 
            (
          props.notes.map((note) => {
            return <ListItem key={note.id} {...note} />;
          })
        ) 
        }
    </div>
)

// The mapStateToProps does not connect with the local state, the action ADD_NOTE fires whenever
// the Create form is submited and the reducer updates the redux storage. So the problem lies here ?
// It could be that state.note is not definded but I don't know where should I define it if I have to, 
// and apparently I don't have to ???????????????

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      notes: state.note
    };
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListGroup);
```

When I try to run this it fires an error:

*ListGroup.js?11a1:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at ListGroup (ListGroup.js?11a1:5)*

Showing that the data that gets passed to the props is undefined. I'm thinking that it could be that state.note is not defined and I have to define it somewhere but I don't know if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Hooks in functional components**

connect() is only valid for class based components. For functional components you need to use hooks. Specifically the useSelector hook for reading redux state and useReducer to emit actions. You can find more instructions on redux hooks here https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector